# (Javascript) multiple condition set for ternary operator issue

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

```
for (var days = 1; days <= 31; ++days) {
    console.log(
        (days == (1, 31, 21) ? days + 'st':'') ||
        (days == (2, 22) ? days + 'nd':'') ||
        (days == (3, 23) ? days + 'rd':'') ||
        days + 'th'
    );
}
```

Trying to display `(1st, 2nd, 3rd)` `(21st, 22nd, 23rd)` `(31st)` `(multiple th)` however I'm getting a strange result here, I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong, any help will be appreciated.

I did try to google and figure this out, promise, just would appreciate a relatively detailed explanation as to why its behaving strange.

Comment: I'd suggest writing your code full out, in `if`s, first. Then try to shorten it with a ternary operator, if you must.

Comment: Also, `days == (1, 31, 21)` isn't going to work. Although it's not invalid syntax, it won't do what you seem to want it to.

Comment: @Cerbrus, thank you for the response, i know what to do now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've typed in some code that is syntactically correct, but it doesn't mean anything like what you apparently expect it to mean.

This:

```
(days == (1, 31, 21) ? days + 'st':'')
```

is in effect exactly the same as

```
(days == 21 ? days + 'st':'')
```

The `(1, 31, 21)` subexpression involves the comma operator, which allows a sequence of expressions (possibly with side-effects) to be evaluated. The overall value is the value of the last expression.

If you want to compare a value to a list of possibilities, in general you can

- use a sequence of `==` (or `===`) comparisons connected by `||`;
- use a `switch` statement with groups of `case` clauses;
- use `.indexOf()` to look for a value in an array.

In this particular case, I'd probably make an array containing the suffixes and then index into it:

```
var suffixes = Array.apply(null, new Array(32)).map(function() { return "th"; });
suffixes[2] = suffixes[22] = "nd";
suffixes[1] = suffixes[21] = suffixes[31] = "st";
suffixes[3] = suffixes[23] = "rd";
```

Then you can just index into the array by day number to get the suffix.

Comment: Alternative: `((days % 10 === 1 && days !== 11) ? days + 'st':'')`

Comment: Right! Makes sense, thanks for the explanation (fast response too!)